# Android BROWSABLE intent API level

Tags: android, android-activity, browsable

Are there different steps to register an Android Activity as a BROWSABLE intent on Android 2.3 (API level 10) and earlier versions?

I've set up an Activity with an intent filter that uses a custom scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data scheme="@string/myCallbackProtocol"/>
</intent-filter>
```

On a physical device running 2.3, and with the SDK's simulator set to 2.3, the browser application directs links using my custom protocol to the app.

However, if I scale back the simulator to 2.2 or 2.1 then the browser does not redirect but instead indicates the server cannot be found. I don't have an actual device running these API levels.

I would like to release my app so it's compatible with devices running 2.1 and greater. Am I wrong to assume this should be possible? According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) `Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` has been available since 1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. `BROWSABLE` works back at least as far as Android 2.1.  Before 2.3 it seems that loading the `<data scheme="">` from a string resource leads to the Activity not being registered correctly.

Changing the `@string/` reference to a hard-coded value yields the desired result.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data scheme="my-custom-protocol"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had no problems using `BROWSABLE` going back at least to 2.1 if not earlier. However, I have not implemented a custom scheme, let alone one defined in a string resource. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/URLHandler) demonstrating the use of `BROWSABLE`.

Comment: hello mark, i want my webview to load the url after it gets pasted in the url field , i tried this uri.setText(intentUri);
   webView.loadUrl(intentUri); but my app force closes. any clue?

Comment: @JRE.exe: I would recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your source code and stack trace.

Comment: here sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452610/load-url-from-browsable-intent-android/28453304?noredirect=1#comment45237116_28453304

Comment: i'm stuck on the same thing since the whole day, were you able to find a workaround? Thanks